# Match pytorch scatter output in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

How can I do the same operation in `tensorflow`?

```
tensor = np.random.RandomState(42).uniform(size=(2, 4, 2)).astype(np.float32)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(tensor)
index = tensor.max(-1, keepdim=True)[1]
output = torch.zeros_like(tensor).scatter_(-1, index, 1.0)

expected output:
tensor([[[0., 1.],
         [1., 0.],
         [1., 0.],
         [0., 1.]],

        [[0., 1.],
         [0., 1.],
         [1., 0.],
         [0., 1.]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, everything is a bit more complicated with Tensorflow:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tensor = np.random.RandomState(42).uniform(size=(2, 4, 2)).astype(np.float32)
tensor = tf.constant(tensor)
_, indices = tf.math.top_k(tensor)
zeros = tf.zeros_like(tensor)

ij = tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(
    tf.range(zeros.shape[0], dtype=tf.int32), 
    tf.range(zeros.shape[1], dtype=tf.int32),
                              indexing='ij'), axis=-1)
gathered_indices = tf.concat([ij, indices], axis=-1)
indices_shape = tf.shape(indices)
values = tf.ones((indices_shape[0], indices_shape[1]))
output = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(zeros, gathered_indices, values)

print(output)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[0. 1.]
  [1. 0.]
  [1. 0.]
  [0. 1.]]

 [[0. 1.]
  [0. 1.]
  [1. 0.]
  [0. 1.]]], shape=(2, 4, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, here's a solution I ended up using.

```
tensor = np.random.RandomState(42).uniform(size=(2, 4, 2)).astype(np.float32)
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(tensor, dtype=tf.float32)


fill_value = 1.0
indices = tf.argmax(tensor, axis=-1)
depth = tensor.shape[-1]
output = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(indices, depth, on_value=fill_value), dtype=tf.float32)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[0. 1.]
  [1. 0.]
  [1. 0.]
  [0. 1.]]

 [[0. 1.]
  [0. 1.]
  [1. 0.]
  [0. 1.]]], shape=(2, 4, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Not generic (if you want to use a different value besides 1) but if it works for your use case. Go for it.

Comment: @AloneTogether I edited the answer a little bit. The variable depth is now taken from the tensor shape. Is that what you were getting at with "if you want to use a different value besides 1"?

Comment: Na. If you want to replace the values in your tensor at certain indices with the value 2 instead of 1...would your solution work?

Comment: @AloneTogether I believe the `on_value` parameter of `tf.one_hot` would do the trick. Check the edit.

Comment: Indeed, but only if all values should be 1 or 2 :)

Comment: @AloneTogether Yes, all the values have to be the same with my solution. But I still upvoted your answer as it is doing what was asked and there's also the added flexibility with the update values.